# bar button in Xcode always goes to bottom Xcode 6.3 beta

Tags: ios, xcode

[image]

when i drag the bar button item onto the view controller they will not stay at the top of the view they will automatically go to the bottom under the table view. Does anyone know what is wrong?

Comment: If you are trying to add it to the navigation bar, check you have a navigationItem on your controller. If not, drag one onto the top then try dragging in your button.

Answer (score 5):

You can fix this by moving the bar button item under the navigation item, inside document outline windows.

**Before**

[image]

**After**

[image]

That should fix the issue. I verified the issue in Xcode 6.3.2

Answer (score 4):

If you navigated to this view-controller via a push segue, it does not have an instance of the navigation bar in storyboard.

You need to drag in a "Navigation Item" object, and then you can add your Bar Button Item on to this.

Comment: this worked for me.  swift 3.1, xcode 7.
odd but seems to work just fine now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

indy and timbrah's fixes didn't work for me... but the below did.

To fix this, select Navigation Item in the Object Library and drag it onto the Root View. Note, it replaces the current one. Then you can drag a Bar Button Item onto as you like.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it seems as if the top bar isn't clearly designated as a navigation bar anymore. I had to select Root View Controller (first icon at the very top left of the screen) then chose the Show Attributes Inspector and at the Top Bar line item under Simulated Metrics chose Translucent Navigation Bar. That enabled it as a navigation bar and I was abled to drag a bar button item there. Weird!

Comment: I had to change it to Opaque Navigation Bar before I could drag and drop it there.

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue today with XCode 7. I have next stack: NC-(root)->VC1-(Show (e.g. Push))->VC2. After I've created VC2 there was no Navigation Item at all. To make it appear I changed segue type from Show (e.g. Push) to Deprecated Push and brought it back to Show (e.g. Push) and now I can use it correctly

Answer (score 0):

You have to drag the Bar Button Item to one of the sides of the navigation controller's navigation bar. So, in your screenshot it would be all the way to the right or left of that bar that has "Root View Controller" in it.

Comment: In Xcode 6.3 that still does not allow you to add a bar button

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell this bug is still around in the 6.3 release. The only way I've been able to add items when this happens is to drag them under the navigation item in the left hand sidebar.

Answer (score 0):

In my situation needed to select ViewControllerScene inside the document outline then forward attributes inspector then change Top Bar to Translucent Navigation Bar